# Why don't my elements stay in their intended place?

Tags: html, css

When I test the code in the jsitor.com things are perfect, as I want them to be. But, I test them in the real website, there is a problem.

In the screenshot below:

1. I want to `float: left` the elements marked in red.
2. Also the delete the space between the word Ads and the top, marked in yellow.

[image: screenshot]

Below is the HTML and CSS code

```css
#aff-ad {
  width: 336px;
  height: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #e6e7e8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.aff-ad-label { 
  float: right;
  color: #bababa;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.aff-ad-title {
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-right: 23px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.79);
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 42px;
  margin-bottom: 12px; 
}
.title_half_background {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #cce7ff 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.aff-ad-dscr {
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-right: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.aff-ad-brand-url {
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-right: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;  
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.aff-ad-btn {
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-right: 23px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 11px;
  background-color: #0188ff;
  width: 265px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;  
}
```

```html
<div style='margin:15px 0;text-align:center;clear:both;'>
<div id="aff-ad">
     <div class="aff-ad-label">ads</div>
     <div class="aff-ad-title"><span class="title_half_background">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</span></div>
     <div class="aff-ad-dscr">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium</div>
     <div class="aff-ad-brand-url">Expo.com</div>
     <a href="http://google.com"><div class="aff-ad-btn">OPEN</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Live demos are great, but it usually helps if you have one demo with your HTML and CSS and not a demo with your HTML and a separate demo with your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put `Ads` on top with no spacing between the border of the box and your element you need to remove `margin-top` from `.aff-ad-label`

changes:

```
.aff-ad-label { 
  float: right;
  color: #bababa;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 2px;              // removed margin top
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this is what you want. and I used bootstrap 5.

```css
#aff-ad {
  width: 336px;
  height: 280px;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #e6e7e8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.aff-ad-label { 
  color: #bababa;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.aff-ad-title {
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-right: 23px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.79);
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 42px;
  margin-bottom: 12px; 
}
.title_half_background {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #cce7ff 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.aff-ad-dscr {
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-right: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.aff-ad-brand-url {
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-right: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;  
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.aff-ad-btn {
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-right: 23px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 11px;
  background-color: #0188ff;
  width: 265px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style='margin:15px 0;text-align:center;clear:both;'>
<div  id="aff-ad">
     <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
     
     <div >
       <div class="aff-ad-title "><span class="title_half_background">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</span>
       </div>
       <div class="aff-ad-dscr">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="aff-ad-label ml-auto">ads</div>
     </div>
     <div class="aff-ad-brand-url">Expo.com</div>
     <a href="http://google.com"><div class="aff-ad-btn">OPEN</div></a>
     
</div>
```